# What are the main differences b/w foreach, parallel foreach and Batch processing in Mule 4

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, mule-esb

In Mule 4, For-each processes records sequentially(using single thread) where as in parallel-foreach and in batch we process records in parallel(multiple threads). I want to know in real time scenarios where to choose what?
Can anyone please explain with real time usecase scenarios, in particular where we have to choose parallel-foreach and where we have to choose batch ?

Comment: Please clarify what do you mean by real time scenarios.

Comment: what I meant was, where we have to use parallel-foreach ? when parallel-foreach is the best choice (when we see comparatively with batch )? when batch is the best choice (when we see comparatively with parallel-foreach)?

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear as to what is meant by real-time in the context of this question. These capabilities are aimed at processing batches of data as opposed to servicing individual requests. If the batches are small in the scenario then some kind of overall real-time processing might be achievable.

Given that I think the best way of addressing the question is as follows.

1) For Each and Parallel For Each (new, introduced in Mule 4.2.0) are very similar so let's review the differences between them

2) Then given 1) above how does For-each processing differ from Batch

---

Item 1) above is addressed in the Mule documentation here https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.2/parallel-foreach-scope#differences-between-for-each-and-parallel-for-each-scopes

Batch and For Each for item 2) above are compared here [Mule batch processing vs foreach vs splitter-aggregator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43413958/mule-batch-processing-vs-foreach-vs-splitter-aggregator)

In short Batch gives the greatest degree of control, flexibility at the expense of being more complex to implement. For Each is more fire and forget. Parallel For Each is more performant than vanilla For Each due to multi-threading but is again more complex as a result e.g. error handling.